# Why can't my Spring Boot build create the .m2 repository in my GitLab CICD pipeline with an OpenShift runner?

Tags: spring-boot, gitlab, gitlab-ci, openshift, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm new to CICD and trying to get a simple build of a Spring Boot Java application on a GitLab CICD pipeline. I am following this tutorial (among others): [about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/12/14/continuous-delivery-of-a-spring-boot-application-with-gitlab-ci-and-kubernetes/](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/12/14/continuous-delivery-of-a-spring-boot-application-with-gitlab-ci-and-kubernetes/)

For my *.gitlab-ci.yml* file, I have the following:

```
image: docker:latest

stages:
  - build

maven-build:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: build
  script: "mvn clean package -B"
  artifacts:
      paths:
        - target/*.jar
```

However, for some reason I keep getting the following error when I run my pipeline:

```
$ mvn clean package -B
[ERROR] Could not create local repository at /.m2/repository -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Despite following the tutorial (and finding other similar ones), I keep getting this error. I have tried the following:

- Verified that the runner works and is able to process the pipeline.
- Verified that the Spring Boot application runs successfully on my
  local machine.
- Tried using different versions of the command (like
  "mvc package -B").
- Compiled the application successfully on my local
  machine using maven command line.

Everything seems to be fine with my code, so why am I getting this error? It is worth noting that my GitLab runner is hosted on OpenShift. Could there be some kind of permissions setting I am overlooking on either GitLab or OpenShift?

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift probably is not letting your GitLab pod to run because of a permission issue. OpenShift by default restricts pods to run under limited permissions. You can check the logs of your pod by running

```
kubectl logs <runner-pod-name>
```

to further debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a script Gitlab CICD for spring boot to build the spring boot using maven and then deploy it to docker as a container. hopefully, this script can help.

```
image: gitlab/dind
services:
  - docker:find
variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
stages:
  - build-test
  - deploy
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
maven-build:
  image: maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17
  stage: build-test
  script: mvn clean install package
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
docker-build:
  stage: deploy
  cache: {}
  script:
    - docker build -t imageName:latest .
    - docker run -d --name yourconatainername -p 8080:8080 imageName:latest
  only:
    - dev
  retry: 1
```

please let me know if you have a specific question for that script. thank you